# R - how to create an incidence matrix

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that links each locus to a pathway.
I want to make an incidence matrix where each row represents a pathway, and each column is locus.  There is a 1 if that locus is in that pathway, otherwise a 0.

I have written something to try and do this, but it is taking too long.  I have about 6 different pathway sets, each with hundreds of pathways, I have almost 6000 locus names.

I am using a complicated double sapply structure.
Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Here is my attempted code which is taking too long.

```
PA14_BioCycAllPwy_binVecs<-sapply(df$pwy_id,function(pwy) {
sapply(PA14_annot_UCSD$PA14_locus,function(loc) ifelse(nrow(subset(df,df$PA14_locus==locus && df$pwy_id==pwy))>0,1,0))
})
```

Here is a sample locus2pathway dataframe.

```
> dput(df[1:100,])
structure(list(PA14_locus = c("PA14_57720", "PA14_57710", "PA14_21370", 
"PA14_21340", "PA14_23560", "PA14_58190", "PA14_58180", "PA14_58170", 
"PA14_61760", "PA14_66750", "PA14_41360", "PA14_41380", "PA14_23560", 
"PA14_60370", "PA14_12230", "PA14_14440", "PA14_52600", "PA14_51820", 
"PA14_08560", "PA14_10420", "PA14_57670", "PA14_28650", "PA14_30330", 
"PA14_51900", "PA14_28710", "PA14_28690", "PA14_19050", "PA14_16530", 
"PA14_14890", "PA14_00100", "PA14_00090", "PA14_08660", "PA14_27610", 
"PA14_27620", "PA14_30680", "PA14_54840", "PA14_41330", "PA14_51660", 
"PA14_60150", "PA14_07470", "PA14_52320", "PA14_61830", "PA14_62790", 
"PA14_68030", "PA14_24870", "PA14_28740", "PA14_60160", "PA14_30420", 
"PA14_51230", "PA14_52560", "PA14_27190", "PA14_08670", "PA14_58710", 
"PA14_68150", "PA14_08690", "PA14_08650", "PA14_41200", "PA14_21810", 
"PA14_24130", "PA14_24120", "PA14_23490", "PA14_60180", "PA14_08590", 
"PA14_23570", "PA14_55634", "PA14_62070", "PA14_70890", "PA14_21800", 
"PA14_24110", "PA14_28190", "PA14_14570", "PA14_41320", "PA14_62800", 
"PA14_65210", "PA14_65220", "PA14_08580", "PA14_55635", "PA14_62080", 
"PA14_70900", "PA14_23580", "PA14_27600", "PA14_61760", "PA14_30720", 
"PA14_03410", "PA14_20500", "PA14_41340", "PA14_52540", "PA14_52550", 
"PA14_60620", "PA14_10850", "PA14_33480", "PA14_36590", "PA14_70270", 
"PA14_36630", "PA14_36840", "PA14_22930", "PA14_68210", "PA14_68190", 
"PA14_68170", "PA14_68200"), pwy_id = c("PWY-5340", "PWY-5340", 
"PWY-5143", "PWY-5143", "PWY-5921", "PWY-5921", "PWY-5921", "PWY-5921", 
"PWY-5921", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", 
"TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "TRNA-CHARGING-PWY", "PWY-5782", "PWY-5782", 
"GLYCOCAT-PWY", "GLYCOCAT-PWY", "GLYCOCAT-PWY", "GLYCOCAT-PWY", 
"GLYCOCAT-PWY", "DTDPRHAMSYN-PWY", "DTDPRHAMSYN-PWY", "DTDPRHAMSYN-PWY", 
"DTDPRHAMSYN-PWY")), .Names = c("PA14_locus", "pwy_id"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is a sample of my list with all of the locus names.

```
> head(PA14_annot_UCSD$PA14_locus)
[1] PA14_28410 PA14_42500 PA14_31260 PA14_28280 PA14_68610 PA14_72540
4434 Levels: EMPTY PA14_00020 PA14_00030 PA14_00070 PA14_00080 PA14_00120 PA14_00150 ... PA14_73410
```

Comment: maybe something with function `categoryReshape` from package `plotrix` ?

Comment: @CathG, this looks great.  I"m just trying to make it work, so I can specify the list of locus names, as not all loci are in the locus2pathway list

Comment: For the locus names that are not in the original data.frame, all associated values will be 0... If you need them in your final data.frame, maybe you can just "add" them after the call to `categoryReshape` ? (I've never used this function, I just know it exits and does what you seem to need...)